# STM32 USB FIFO address

Tags: stm32

I am using STM32F407 USB_FS in device mode. The setup packet I get from the host correspondes to:

```
01 CC 00 80 - control
01 00 06 80 - data
00 40 00 00 - data
```

3
This data looks ok. I am reading from the pop register at address 0x50001000. However if I read from 0x50002000 or 0x50001000 or indeed any address in that range I get the same reading which is odd. Are these FIFO registers somehow protected and the application is forced to read from one location? Its not very clear in the reference manual where exactly the FIFO address are and the endpoint addresses associated with them. Can anybody clarify that?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no FIFO. You have the data from  the endpoints buffers, and you set their addresses yourself. Did you read he RM?. Do you know how USB works?

Comment: Page 1261 of the RM clearly defines both Rx and Tx Fifo's. The data above was read from the Rx Fifo. With regards to setting the endpoint addresses that is unclear in the RM. It defines endpoint configuration but nothing to do with endpoint location.